# Programatically add tab linked to ui.router

Tags: angularjs

I have the following configuration for my $stateProvider:

```
$stateProvider
    .state("main", { abstract: true, url: "/main", templateUrl: "main.html" })
    .state("main.tab1", { url: "/tab1", templateUrl: "tab1.html" })
    .state("main.tab2", { url: "/tab2", templateUrl: "tab2.html" })
    .state("main.tab3", {
        url: "/tab3/{id}",
        templateUrl: "tab3.html",
        controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
            console.log("ID is " + $stateParams.id)
            $scope.id = $stateParams.id;
        }
     });
```

I'm organising the main content into tabs under this controller:

```
<div ng-controller="mainController">
    <tabset>
        <tab ng-repeat="t in tabs"
             heading="{{t.heading}}"
             select="go(t.route)"
             active="t.active">
        </tab>
    </tabset>

    <h2>View:</h2>
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

Now, through a button with an ng-click in main.html I'm calling this function:

```
$scope.tabs.push({heading: "Tab 3", route: "main.tab3", active: true})
```

My intention is to be able to push a new entry onto the tabs object which will then load content into a newly created tab through the $stateProvider configuration.

The question is, how can I pass a parameter through the route, as if I were invoking /tab3/1234 directly?

Answer (score 1):

If you have separate template for every tab, then you may be want to change your concept. `<tabset>` directive is really not for dynamic work.

Here is the fiddle I created for tabs demonstration.

http://jsfiddle.net/Serhioromano/t7s3jrg4/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" ng-app="MyTabs">
    <div class="page-header">
         <h1><a href="#/tab/1">Site Name</a></h1>

    </div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li ng-class="{'active': tab == 1}"> <a href="#/tab/1">Pictures</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{'active': tab == 2}"> <a href="#/tab/2">Posts</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{'active': tab == 3}"> <a href="#/tab/3">Videos</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{'active': tab == 4}"> <a href="#/tab/4">Other</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div ui-view></div>
    <footer>    
        <small>Build with Tabs</small>
    </footer>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('MyTabs', ['ui.router'])
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/1');

    $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            url: "/tab",
            abstract: true,
            template: "<div ui-view></div>",
            controller: function ($scope) {
                $scope.form = {};
            }
        })
        .state('app.tab', {
            url: '/:tab',
            template: function ($stateParams) {
                return '<h2>This is tab ' + $stateParams.tab + 
                  '</h2><input type="text" ng-model="form.name' + $stateParams.tab + '" />';
            },
            controller: function ($scope, $state, $stateParams, $rootScope, $log) {
                $rootScope.tab = parseInt($stateParams.tab);
            }
    });
})
    .run(function () {});
```

You provide template based on tab URL dynamically.this mean you can add as many tabs as you want. You can even create a separate controller for every tab with something like this.

```
controllerProvider: function($stateParams) {
      var ctrlName = "Controller" + $stateParams.tab;
      return ctrlName;
}
```

or you can load templates dynamically with something like this

```
templateUrl: function ($stateParams) {
     return 'partials/' + $stateParams.tab + '.html';
},
```